# What kind of protection could this be?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, escaping, jsfiddle

I was testing stuff in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) (with jQuery 1.9.0 included as an external ressource), and I basically had something like this in my HTML :

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('Hello world');">Hello world!</a>
```

Under Chrome Inspector (v.35) / Script / index file, I spotted that **AdBlock Plus** (even toggled off) *probably* added these lines in my HTML's source :

```
<script>
    (function () {
        with(this[2]) {
            with(this[1]) {
                with(this[0]) {
                    return function (event) {
                        alert('Hello world!'); //Same as my onclick up there
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

I've never seen something like this, I guess it is meant to be a protection, but I can't figure what's its purpose.

What could do this code? Any guess?

**Disclaimer : I'm sorry, I tried hard but I'm absolutely unable to reproduce this for the moment, apart for my own case...**

---

### Edit

I though it was impossible to reproduce even by opening my fiddle in another tab, but in fact, it seems to be possible. So, here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bigood/GFZ9K/2/), activate **AdBlock plus**, and here's how to see this :

[image]

Meanwhile, I'm trying to create a case where it's 100% reproductible, I'll post it here as soon as possible.

Comment: Can you post a link to the fiddle with this problem?

Comment: I'm not seeing that in the console at all ?

Comment: It seems unlikely that jsfiddle would add that automatically, since `with` is deprecated.

Comment: @Barmar I added the fiddle, I thought it wasn't reproductible at all, my bad.

Comment: Possible browser extension?

Comment: @j08691 Processing...

Comment: I see it in `jsfiddle.net/bigood/GFZ9K/2/index`, but not in `fiddle.jshell.net/bigood/GFZ9K/2/show/index`. Weird.

Comment: That code doesn't seem to do anything at all. It creates an anonymous function, but it never calls it or assigns it to anything. Maybe the purpose is to trigger a syntax error if the code in an `onXXX` block is invalid JS?

Comment: @Barmar Agreed, it's never called. Note the parenthesis around the function, to wrap it in its own scope too. The syntax error might be a good lead...

Comment: Nice call @j08691! Well, I think it's **Adblock Plus** (even if it's toggled off, I had to deactivate it). It doesn't change much of the problem, the code's still the same but the context's different ; we now have a more accurate idea of the possible purpose of it.

Comment: Yeah I see it when I run Chrome normally (which includes AdBlock) but it's gone when I test in incognito mode where AdBlock isn't running.

Comment: neat... you might want to log out the specific indexes its nesting into, I have never seen any global indexes so whatever is there was injected. its definitely not on my system.

Comment: @Shanimal I try to, but it keep disappearing when I'm trying to breakpoint it. I'm looking into ADP's source right now to understand it.

Comment: Damn, I can't even find the origin of it. I think I'm going to stop there for now. Thank you for your time!